# Add value with previous date to actual date in query result

Tags: sql, group-by, mariadb, pivot, mariadb-10.3

[**DB-Fiddle:**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=aca0542e1f44b663606c3baa99318ba4)

```
CREATE TABLE logistics (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    flow_date DATE,
    flow_type VARCHAR(255),
    flow_quantity INT
);

INSERT INTO logistics
(flow_date, flow_type, flow_quantity
)
VALUES 
("2020-04-18", "inbound", "500"),
("2020-04-18", "outbound", "400"),
("2020-04-18", "stock", "100"),
("2020-04-19", "inbound", "800"),
("2020-04-19", "outbound", "650"),
("2020-04-19", "stock", "250"),
("2020-04-20", "inbound", "730"),
("2020-04-20", "outbound", "600"),
("2020-04-20", "stock", "380"),
("2020-04-21", "inbound", "420"),
("2020-04-21", "outbound","370"),
("2020-04-21", "stock", "430");
```

**Expected Result:**

```
flow_date     stock_yesterday   inbound    outbound    stock_today
2020-04-18         0              500        -400         100        
2020-04-19        100             800        -650         250
2020-04-20        250             730        -600         380
2020-04-21        380             420        -370         430
```

---

Basically, in my result I want to show this timelime: `stock_yesterday + inbound - outbound = stock_today`. 
 
Therefore, I need to change the original table like the following:

a) The `flow_types` are used as `columns` in the result. 
a) The `stock_yesterday` is the `flow_quantity` of the `flow_type` `stock` of the previous day. 
b) All other `flow_types` refer to the same `flow_date`.

---

So far I came up with this query but could not make it work:

```
SELECT
flow_date,
(CASE WHEN flow_type = "inbound" THEN flow_quantity END) AS inbound,
(CASE WHEN flow_type = "outbound" THEN flow_quantity END) AS outbound,
(CASE WHEN flow_type = "stock" THEN flow_quantity END) AS stock_today
FROM logistics
GROUP BY 1;
```

It only displays the `inbound`. 
I also have no clue how I could add the `stock_yesterday` to the query.

What do I need to change in my query to get the expected result?

Comment: If you already have `stock` why do you need to compute it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions and aggregation:

```
select
    flow_date,
    sum(inbound + outbound) 
        over(order by flow_date rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) stock_yesterday,
    inbound,
    outbound,
    sum(inbound + outbound) over(order by flow_date) stock_today
from (
    select 
        flow_date,
        sum(case when flow_type = 'inbound' then flow_quantity else 0 end) inbound,
        sum(case when flow_type = 'outbound' then -flow_quantity else 0 end) outbound
    from logistics
    group by flow_date
) t
order by flow_date
```

The subquery is not stricly necessary, but it helps shortening the syntax.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=95132c69b3c06bb87775958894c3af65)**:

```
flow_date  | stock_yesterday | inbound | outbound | stock_today
:--------- | --------------: | ------: | -------: | ----------:
2020-04-18 |            null |     500 |     -400 |         100
2020-04-19 |             100 |     800 |     -650 |         250
2020-04-20 |             250 |     730 |     -600 |         380
2020-04-21 |             380 |     420 |     -370 |         430
```